# I18n::ArgumentError in Admin/main#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am newbie to ruby devlopment.
I got this error:

> Showing
>   /home/User/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/gems/admin-0.0.5/app/views/admin/main/index.html.haml
>   where line #129 raised:
>
> Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your admin/main/index.html.haml file and your admin/main_controller.rb files please

Comment: @Mark admin/main/index.html.haml doesn't exist  i don't know why i got this error I forget to write that the project was working fine on the hosted server and know it doesn't

Comment: Semantics, but that file does exist, not in your project but in the gem (as you can see in the path). What admin gem are you using? Could you point us to it?

Comment: @Leito I am using rails_admin 0.0.4  and when i click on invoices link I get this error intead of list of invoices

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without knowing which "admin" gem and all, but I've seen this error when passing a nil value to the `I18n.localize` (`I18n.l`) method, which will be common in admin interfaces.

The complete error message is:
`I18n::ArgumentError: Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. nil given.`

So, one of your records have a nil date where it's not supposed too. Maybe `:created_at` or `:updated_at` are `nil` or another date.

Comment: Thank you, I got this error when i try to get list of invoices in rails_admin generated which is already worked before migrating to heroku

Comment: One of your invoices in your Heroku's DB has a nil date where it's not supposed too, my guess is still in the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. But it could be on any date displayed on the invoices index page. Maybe something went wrong migrating the data to Heroku, connect to the rails console and verify this: `Invoice.where(created_at: nil).count`, same with :`updated_at`

Comment: could you please tell me  how to connect to rails console to verify. Regards

Comment: `heroku run rails console`, make sure you review Heroku's guide for Rails: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5. Make sue how you migrated the data was the right way, etc.

Comment: I got this errors: column invoices.updated_at does not exist, column invoices.created_at does not exist

Comment: I don't know your project, should they exist? Have you run the migrations?
 See the guide i mentioned before. You do have a Invoice model right? What bout `Invoice.count`?

Comment: It shouldn't change much, if it does, find the right guide for your version. Please update your question with any relevant information you find. I suspect you have bigger issues with your Heroku setup than the one error described above.

Comment: it is not problem just with heroku even in local I am testing and i got the same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153704/discussion-between-leito-and-essen).